# Why does the sum of two adjacent sections of bitstream in an LFSR generate the same taps as the individual sections?

Tags: lfsr

I have the sum (bitwise XOR) of 2 adjacent sections of bitstream in a 61 bit LFSR, I know what the taps should be for each individual section. When I feed this combined bitstream into a Berlekamp-Massey tool, it gives the same taps as the taps for each individual section. Why is this?